# How do I extract a value from a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects shown below :

```
images = [{"image":"Admin/Public/01.png"},{"image":"Admin/Public/02.png"},{"image":"Admin/Public/03.png"}]
```

I need to extract the values of objects from the above list, so I get a result like :

```
images = 'Admin/Public/01.png, Admin/Public/02.png, Admin/Public/03.png'
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension like this:

```py
images = [{"image":"Admin/Public/01.png"},{"image":"Admin/Public/02.png"},{"image":"Admin/Public/03.png"}]

# Use list comprehension to extract the values and join them with a delimeter
images_list = ', '.join([img['image'] for img in images])

# Print the output
print(images_list)

## Output
'Admin/Public/01.png, Admin/Public/02.png, Admin/Public/03.png'
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a for loop like this:

```
for obj in images: 
    print( obj.image)
```

and then you can append it in a new object with , as a separator:

```
final = ''
final+=','+obj.image
```